# Inserting spaces between text of elements with same name

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

this question is probably fairly trivial to answer for versed XSLT authors.

I have the following example XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<students>
    <student num="12345678">
        <name>Dona Diller</name>
        <dob>1970-07-21</dob>
        <education>BSc</education>
        <education>MSc</education>
        <status>Married</status>
    </student>

<!-- more student elements to follow... -->

</students>
```

And the following XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <title>Test</title>
            <body>
                <h1>Personal details</h1>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="students/student"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="student">
        <p>
            Student number:
            <xsl:value-of select="@num"/>
        </p>
        <p>Full name:
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </p>
        <p>Date of birth
            <xsl:value-of select="dob"/>
        </p>
        <!-- TODO: text of 'education' elements must be separated by a space -->
        <p>Degrees:
            <xsl:apply-templates select="education"/>
        </p>
        <p>Status:
            <xsl:value-of select="status"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces the following XHTML output when applied to the XML document included at the beginning of this post:

```
<html>
   <title>Test</title>
   <body>
      <h1>Personal details</h1>
      <p>
         Student number:
         12345678
      </p>
      <p>Full name:
         Dona Diller
      </p>
      <p>Date of birth
         1970-07-21
      </p>
      <p>Degrees:
         BScMSc
      </p>
      <p>Status:
         Married
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

My issue is that the degree names are merged as one string (text of education element). So instead of getting 'BScMSc' in the output, I'd like to display 'BSc MSc' in the previous example. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

The solutions by Novatchev and Honnen will both work (of course) but something about them feels a little unsatisfactory to me. I think if you're going to delegate formatting of an education element to a template rule, then that template rule ought only to be concerned with the formatting of one education element, and not with the formatting of a set of adjacent elements. To me, the interstitial spacing is properly the job of the parent template. So I think I would be inclined to write:

```
<xsl:for-each select="education">
  <xsl:if test="position() ne 1"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: or !=  rather than ne if you are stuck at xslt 1.0  as indicated in the OP's stylesheet:-)

Comment: In my response I tred to provide the shortest possible solution I can think of. This intentionally excludes any conditinals or the use of `xsl:text`.

Comment: In my response I tred to provide the shortest possible solution I can think of. This intentionally excludes any conditinals or the use of `xsl:text`. Martin's solution occupies 6 lines and has an unnecessary explicit conditional. Your solution occupies 4 lines, one of them rather long, uses `xsl:for-each`, has an explicit conditional and also doesn't strike as too-readable. Also, sometimes there is a template matching `text()` specified by the author with a different behavior than the built-in XSLT template. My code makes no assumptions about the behavior of any templates matching `text()`.

Answer (score 2):

Add a template

```
<xsl:template match="education">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Shorter/simpler/more-readable**

**Add this template**:

```
<xsl:template match="education[position() > 1]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', .)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a space to the end of every degree:

```
<xsl:template match="education">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Yes, this results in an extraneous space at the end of the list of degrees, but that's not a problem in this case.

If you have XSLT 2.0, you could try

```
<p>Degrees:
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join(education,' ')"/>
</p>
```